# JavaScript browser compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an issue in my JavaScript function.

Below is my js code:

```
function abc(formobject){
    var ext =".txt";
         var abc=".doc,docx";
    if(abc.search(ext) < 0){
        alert("hi"); 
        formobject.file.value="";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

<input type="submit" id="button"  value="submit" onclick="return abc(this.form);">
```

Here on click of submit button I am calling `abc()` js function and uploading the file. It executes the logic and if the file is of not valid extension it should throw alert and clear the values of browse button. Its happening in Mozilla, but the values are not getting cleared in IE8. Can anyone help me on this?

File is the `<html:file property="file"/>` which I am uploading here.

Comment: can you post code for you'r file tag as well?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973661/ie8-causing-file-input-entry-to-be-blank-via-sendkeys

Apparently it isn't possible for security reasons.

Comment: <TD><html:file property="file"/></TD>

Comment: Ankit formobject.reset() resets all the values of other text boxes in form also

Comment: I want only the browse button values to be cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
formobject.file.value="";
```

try using

```
formobject.reset();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming that you have only "browse" field in your form.

There is no access to value field of file input tag because of security restriction. more on this at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx

If you want to clear only file field then you have to add a div tag before your file field and clear it.

Example:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(formobject){     
var ext =".txt";          
var abc=".doc,docx";     
if(abc.search(ext) < 0){         
alert("hi");          
document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML;

return false;     
}     
return true; 
} 


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="theForm">
<div id="uploadFile_div">
<INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file">
</div>
<input type="submit" id="button"  value="submit" onclick="return abc(this.form);">

</body>
```